# python3: understand usage of `setdefault` dictionary method

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have seen the following code snippet:

```
# list representing sequence of states
states = ['a','b','c','d','a','a','a','b','c','b','b','b']

# matrix of transitions
M = {}

for i in range(len(states)-1):
    M.setdefault((states[i], states[i+1]), [0])[0] += 1
```

So it walks the list and counts the transitions, e.g. `a->b`, `b->c`, `c->c` and so on. I understand that `setdefault()` would insert default value if key is not in dictionary. However I don't understand why the default value is a list itself, in this case it is [0]. Also `M.setdefault(...)[0]` means we always pick the 1st element of the list and increment it.

What could be the reason of such approach?

Comment: This is not legal Python code.

Comment: Without any explanation as to what this code is trying to accomplish, how do you expect someone to explain this particular implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as you understood it - as to why a list-value is used instead of directly using an integer - it does not work using a "pure" integer and `setdefault(..)`.

**Reason:**  The `setdefault()` returns the value of your dictionary for this key. If you return a list you get a *reference* to that list. If you modify the list, the change reflects inside the dictionary (because: reference). If you use a integer you get it returned, but modifying it does not change the value that is assigned to the key inside the dict.

```
# list representing sequence of states
states = ['a','b','c','d','a','a','a','b','c','b','b','b']

# matrix of transitions
M = {}

for i in range(len(states)-1):
    M.setdefault((states[i], states[i+1]), [0])[0] += 1

print(M)
```

Output:

```
{('a', 'b'): 2, ('b', 'c'): 2, ('c', 'd'): 1, ('d', 'a'): 1, 
 ('a', 'a'): 2, ('c', 'b'): 1, ('b', 'b'): 2}
```

If you want to *not* use a list containing a single counter integer, you could do:

```
for i in range(len(states)-1):

    # does not work, error:   M.setdefault((states[i], states[i+1]), 0) += 1 
    M.setdefault((states[i], states[i+1]), 0)  
    M[(states[i], states[i+1])] += 1
print(M)
```

Output:

```
{('a', 'b'): 2, ('b', 'c'): 2, ('c', 'd'): 1, ('d', 'a'): 1, 
 ('a', 'a'): 2, ('c', 'b'): 1, ('b', 'b'): 2}
```

but that takes two lines - you cannot directly assign to a integer.

I personally would probably do:

```
# list representing sequence of states
states = ['a','b','c','d','a','a','a','b','c','b','b','b']

# matrix of transitions 
from collections import defaultdict
M = defaultdict(int)

for a, b in zip(states,states[1:]):
    M[(a,b)] += 1 

print(dict(M))  # or use M directly - its str-output is not that nice though
```

which should be more performant then using a base dictionaries `setdefault`.

Comment: Patrick, thank you for the comprehensive answer. The fact that _returning a list would get a reference to that list_ -- is it a property of Pyhon lists only, or any iterative objects? Also, why does `M.setdefault((states[i], states[i+1]), 0) += 1` fail?

Comment: @Mark because the original thing stores lists. You retreive a copy of the reference to the list from the dict and modify throught it the data both references are pointing to. Your try returns a copy of an integer - if you modify it you do not modify the original one, you merely assign your copy of it a new value.